# How to create credit memo programmatically in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need to create credit memo and online refund programmatically in magento 2. I referred programmatic creation of credit memo in magento 1.x [here](http://magentotutorial.in/how-to-create-credit-memo-programmatically-in-magento/). Any help for magento 2?

Comment: Check for order item wise creditmemo, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-creditmemo-for-order-item-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 13):

Finally discovered the solution, to create credit memo with online refund from custom code. Use this code in your custom model and call the function where ever you want.

```
public __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory $creditmemoFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService $creditmemoService,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($data);
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->creditmemoFactory = $creditmemoFactory;
    $this->creditmemoService = $creditmemoService;
    $this->invoice = $invoice; 
}

public function refundCode()
{
    $order = $this->order;
    $order->load(10);

    $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        $invoiceincrementid = $invoice->getIncrementId();
    }

    $invoiceobj = $this->invoice->loadByIncrementId($invoiceincrementid);
    $creditmemo = $this->creditmemoFactory->createByOrder($order);

    // Don't set invoice if you want to do offline refund
    $creditmemo->setInvoice($invoiceobj);

    $this->creditmemoService->refund($creditmemo); 
}
```

Comment: How to pass here an array of specific items?

Comment: Hi @zhartaunik do we have combination of your code & zhartaunik's answer in Refund it automatically includes Shipping Fee. How to avoid that?

Comment: Doesn't work in 2.1.6 and 2.1.7 - throws an error "We don't have enough information to save the parent transaction ID"

Comment: How to change order status from closed to cancel when credit memo is created?

Comment: do you know how to return  to stock for an item?

Answer (score 5):

Here some function which can be helpful to you

Create a creditmemo from an order:

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory::createByOrder
```

Refund a creditmemo:

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService::refund
```

Answer (score 5):

Magento 2.1.3

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory
 */
protected $refundOrder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\ItemCreationFactory
 */
protected $itemCreationFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\RefundOrder $refundOrder,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\ItemCreationFactory $itemCreationFactory
) {
    $this->refundOrder = $refundOrder;
    $this->itemCreationFactory = $itemCreationFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $creditmemoItem = $this->itemCreationFactory->create();
    $creditmemoItem->setQty(1)
          ->setOrderItemId(22);
    $itemIdsToRefund[] = $creditmemoItem;

    $this->refundOrder->execute(
        $order->getId(),
        $itemIdsToRefund
    );
}
```

Runs as clockwork

Comment: Can i get refund related table fields bz i want to create csv template for data migration.

Comment: How can I pass invoice id for same?

Comment: can we refund amout to storecredit  ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anyway to do an online refund using Magento\Sales\Model\RefundOrder. It will always be offline.

Answer (score 1):

To do a partial credit memo against an invoice, you need to do something like this:

```
/** @var RefundInvoiceInterface $refundInvoice */
$refundInvoice = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Sales\Api\RefundInvoiceInterface");

$items = []; // If items is empty array, the entire invoice will be refunded.

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item $item */
foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {

    // Note that the simple and configurable products are returned in getAllItems(). The function getVisibleItems() does not work, so we need this check:
    if($item->getOrderItem()->getProductType() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        continue;
    }

    $qtyToReturn = 1; // Select out many you want to refund
    $creditmemoItemCreation = new \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\ItemCreation();
    $items[] = $creditmemoItemCreation->setQty($qtyToReturn)->setOrderItemId($item->getOrderItemId());
}

// If you don't want to refund shipping, or to make adjustment refunds, use the CreationArguments (otherwise, you can leave these next two lines out)
$creditMemoCreationArguments = new CreationArguments();
$creditMemoCreationArguments->setShippingAmount(0);

$refundInvoice->execute($invoice->getId(), $items, true, true, false, null, $creditMemoCreationArguments);
```

Comment: Seems to possibly be something missing, where does `$invoice` get defined? It also seems like the `$items` array gets overwritten...

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); /* Instance of object manager */


$incrementId = "100075273"; /*Increment Id */

$collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order'); 
$order = $collection->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

$invoice = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice');

$creditMemoFacory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory');
$creditmemoService = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService');

try {
    $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        $invoiceincrementid = $invoice->getIncrementId();
    }

if(isset($invoiceincrementid)){
    $invoiceobj = $invoice->loadByIncrementId($invoiceincrementid);
    $creditmemo = $creditMemoFacory->createByOrder($order);

// Don't set invoice if you want to do offline refund
$creditmemo->setInvoice($invoiceobj);

$creditmemoService->refund($creditmemo); 

echo "CreditMemo Succesfully Created For Order: ".$incrementId;

} else {
    echo "CreditMemo Cannot Be Created For Order: ".$incrementId; /*if order has 0 amount or something wrong happened**/
}

} catch (\Exception $e) {
   echo "Creditmemo Not Created". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: How to do a partial refund ?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I got it working on Magento 2.3. All you need to pass is just the Order object.

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Package\Model\Order\Processor;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService;


class CustomClass
{
    protected $creditMemoFactory;
    protected $creditMemoService;
    protected $invoice;


    public function __construct (
        CreditmemoFactory $creditMemoFactory,
        CreditmemoService $creditMemoService,
        Invoice $invoice
    ) {
        $this->creditMemoFactory = $creditMemoFactory;
        $this->creditMemoService = $creditMemoService;
        $this->invoice = $invoice;
    }


    /**
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function refund(OrderInterface $order): void
    {
        $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();

        if (count($invoices) == 0) {
            throw new \Exception(__('No Invoices found for Refund. Magento_ID: %2',
                $order->getIncrementId()));
        }

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            $invoice = $this->invoice->loadByIncrementId($invoice->getIncrementId());
            $creditMemo = $this->creditMemoFactory->createByOrder($order);

            // Don't set invoice if you want to do offline refund
            $creditMemo->setInvoice($invoice);
            $creditMemo->setCustomerNote(__('Your Order %1 has been Refunded back in your account',
                $order->getIncrementId()));
            $creditMemo->setCustomerNoteNotify(false);
            $creditMemo->addComment(__('Order has been Refunded'));

            $order->addCommentToStatusHistory(__('Order has been Refunded Successfully'));

            $this->creditMemoService->refund($creditMemo);
        }
    }
}


I hope it helps.
```