# magento 2 Programmatically create a credit memo by script

Tags: magento2, creditmemo, script

Given an order that has been invoiced (by cash on delivery for testing) and is in state "processing", how can I create a credit memo?
**in code that is outside of Magento routing**

**EDIT:**

I have found many solutions for creating a credit memo. But I want to create a credit memo from the root of Magento.

Comment: we need to code inside the magento 2 root just like a custome script to perticuller to one order is generate the credit memo.

Comment: I reopened your question. Becuase you have different question than other. Check my answer for creating credit memo from the root.

Comment: If you know how to create a credit memo then the question is not how to do that, but how to do something from the root of Magento. So then your question would be duplicate of the question how to run a script from the root of Magento...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the script for creating credit memo from Magento root

Create `createcreditmemo.php` at the root of magento

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface');

//Use this if you have orderId
//$orderId = "100"; //Order Id
//$order = $orderInterface->load($orderId);

$incrementId = "000000214"; //Increment Id
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
        ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', $incrementId);
$invoice = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice');
$creditMemoFacory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory');
$creditmemoService = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService');

try {
    $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        $invoiceincrementid = $invoice->getIncrementId();
    }

    $invoiceobj = $invoice->loadByIncrementId($invoiceincrementid);
    $creditmemo = $creditMemoFacory->createByOrder($order);

    // Don't set invoice if you want to do offline refund
    $creditmemo->setInvoice($invoiceobj);

    $creditmemoService->refund($creditmemo); 

    echo "CreditMemo Succesfully Created For Order: ".$incrementId;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   echo "Creditmemo Not Created". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Change order increment id or order id as per your requirement. And run this script at the root of Magento to create creditmemo.

Comment: How to  create credit memo by product item not all items

Answer (score 3):

Your Can Creaditmemo Using Below code.

```
protected $refundOrder;

public function __construct(
     \Magento\Sales\Model\RefundOrder $refundOrder,
     \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\ItemCreationFactory $itemCreationFactory
){
     $this->refundOrder = $refundOrder;
     $this->itemCreationFactory = $itemCreationFactory;
}

public function creaditMemo($itemId, $qty, $orderId) {

        try {
            $creditmemoItem = $this->itemCreationFactory->create();
            $creditmemoItem->setQty($qty)->setOrderItemId($itemId);
            $itemIdsToRefund[] = $creditmemoItem;
            $this->refundOrder->execute($orderId, $itemIdsToRefund);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            throw $ex;
        }
    }
```

Pass Your Item Id, Qty of CreaditMemo for that item & OrderId.

Comment: we need to code inside the magento 2 root just like a custome script to perticuller to one order is generate the credit memo.

Comment: You can also refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139661/51548

Comment: we need to code custome just like  

<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 echo "<pre>";
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

Comment: How can I do online refund using same?

Comment: How to pass here an array of specific items?

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: do you know how to return  to stock for an item?