# Magento 2 - Create partial Credit Memo programmatically

Tags: orders, magento2.3, sales-order, creditmemo

I can create Credit Memo for invoice as given in [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221702/magento-2-programmatically-create-a-credit-memo-by-script).

Can anyone please help me to create Credit Memo with **partial products and not returning all the products in invoice**.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento, if you want to create a credit memo, then you need to use below class:

- `\Magento\Sales\Api\RefundOrderInterface`
- `\Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface`
- `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ CreditmemoItemInterfaceFactory`

### Example:

```
<?php


namespace {namespace};

class {ClassName}  
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $CreditmemoItemCreationFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $invoiceRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\RefundOrderInterface
     */
    private $refundOrder;



    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Sales\Api\RefundOrderInterface $refundOrder,
         \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface $invoiceRepository,
         \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemInterfaceFactory $CreditmemoItemCreationFactory 
        ) {
        $this->refundOrder = $refundOrder;
        $this->invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
        $this->CreditmemoItemCreationFactory = $CreditmemoItemCreationFactory;
    }
    public function execute() 
    {
        $invoiceId = 5;
        try{
            
            $invoice= $this->invoiceRepository->get($invoiceId);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $ex) {
            return ;
        }
        
        $invoiceItems = $invoice->getItems();
        $items = [];
        $orderId = $invoice->getOrderId();
        
        foreach ($invoiceItems as $invoiceItem) {
            

            if($invoiceItem->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()){
                continue;
            }
            
            $productId = $invoiceItem->getProductId();
            $invoiceSku = $invoiceItem->getSku();
            
            /**
             * If product id match then create Credit memo for that order
             */
            if($productId === 2030){
                $creditmemoItemCreation = $this->CreditmemoItemCreationFactory->create();
                $items[] = $creditmemoItemCreation->setQty($invoiceItem->getQty())
                         ->setOrderItemId($invoiceItem->getOrderItemId());                
            }
            


            
                    
        }

        

        /**
         * Create Credit Memo
         */
        
        $this->refundOrder->execute($orderId, $items, true, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: How to add comment in that credit memo ?

Comment: do you know how to return  to stock for an item?